# Is there a way to gracefully end a pod with the Kubernetes client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

The main question is if there is a way to finish a pod from the **client-go sdk**, I'm not trying to delete a pod, I just want to finish it with a Phase-Status: **Completed**.

In the code, I'm trying to update the pod phase but It doesn't work, It does not return an error or panic but The pod does not finish.
My code:

```
func main() {

    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for {

        pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("ns").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        for _, pod := range pods.Items {

            podName:= pod.Name
            if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(podName), "single-condition") {
            
                fmt.Println("get pods metadatada")
                fmt.Println(pod.Name)
                fmt.Printf("pod.Name %s \n", pod.Name)
                fmt.Printf("Status.Phase %s \n", pod.Status.Phase)
                fmt.Printf("PodIP %s \n", pod.Status.PodIP)

                containers := pod.Status.ContainerStatuses
                if len(containers) > 0 {
                    for _ ,c := range containers {
                        fmt.Printf("c.Name %s \n", c.Name)
                        fmt.Printf("c.State %s \n", c.State)
                        fmt.Printf("c.State.Terminated %s \n", c.State.Terminated)

                        stateTerminated := c.State.Terminated
                        stateRunning := c.State.Running
                        if stateTerminated == nil && stateRunning != nil {
                            fmt.Printf("c.State.Terminated %s \n", c.State.Terminated)
                            fmt.Printf("stateRunning Reason: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(c.State.Running))

                            getPod, getErr := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("ns").Get(context.TODO(), "single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659" , metav1.GetOptions{})
                            if getErr != nil {
                                fmt.Println("error1")
                                panic(fmt.Errorf("Failed to get: %v", getErr))
                            }
                            fmt.Println("update values")
                            fmt.Printf(" getPodName %d \n", getPod.Name)
                            getPod.Status.Phase = "Succeeded"
                            fmt.Println("updated status phase")
                            getContainers := getPod.Status.ContainerStatuses
                            fmt.Printf("len get container %d \n", len(getContainers))
                            _, updateErr := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("argo-workflows").Update(context.TODO(), getPod, metav1.UpdateOptions{})
                            fmt.Println("commit update")
                            if updateErr != nil {
                                fmt.Println("error updated")
                                panic(fmt.Errorf("Failed to update: %v", updateErr))
                            }

                        } else {
                            fmt.Printf("c.State.Terminated %s \n", c.State.Terminated.Reason)
                            //fmt.Println("Not finished ready!!!")
                            //fmt.Printf("c.State.Running %s \n", c.State.Running)
                            //fmt.Printf("c.State.Waiting %s \n", c.State.Waiting)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    }
}
```

and some logs:

```
single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659
pod.Name single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659 
Status.Phase Running 
PodIP XXXXXXXXXXXX
c.Name main 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c.State {nil &ContainerStateRunning{StartedAt:2021-10-29 04:41:51 +0000 UTC,} nil} 
c.State.Terminated nil 
c.State.Terminated nil 
stateRunning Reason: *v1.ContainerStateRunning
update values
 getPodName %!d(string=single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659) 
updated status phase
len get container 2 
commit update
c.Name wait 
c.State {nil &ContainerStateRunning{StartedAt:2021-10-29 04:41:51 +0000 UTC,} nil} 
c.State.Terminated nil 
c.State.Terminated nil 
stateRunning Reason: *v1.ContainerStateRunning
update values
 getPodName %!d(string=single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659) 
updated status phase
len get container 2 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
commit update
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
get pods metadatada
single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659
pod.Name single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659 
Status.Phase Running 
PodIP XXXXXXXXXX 
c.Name main 
c.State {nil &ContainerStateRunning{StartedAt:2021-10-29 04:41:51 +0000 UTC,} nil} 
c.State.Terminated nil 
c.State.Terminated nil 
stateRunning Reason: *v1.ContainerStateRunning
update values
 getPodName %!d(string=single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659) 
updated status phase
len get container 2 
commit update
c.Name wait 
c.State {nil &ContainerStateRunning{StartedAt:2021-10-29 04:41:51 +0000 UTC,} nil} 
c.State.Terminated nil 
c.State.Terminated nil 
stateRunning Reason: *v1.ContainerStateRunning
update values
 getPodName %!d(string=single-condition-pipeline-9rqrs-1224102659) 
updated status phase
len get container 2 
commit update
```

so here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-status, It mentions a Patch but I don't know how to use it, so if somebody could help me or if there is another way to finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `phase` or anything else in the Pod `status` field, it is [read only](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#pod-v1-core). According to the [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) documentation your pod will have a phase of `Succeeded` after *"All containers in the Pod have terminated in success, and will not be restarted."* So this will only happen if you can cause all of your pod's containers to exit with status code `0` and if the pod `restartPolicy` is set to `onFailure` or `Never`, if it is set to `Always` (the default) then the containers will eventually restart and your pod will eventually return to the `Running` phase.

In summary, you cannot do what you are attempting to do via the Kube API directly. You must:

1. Ensure your pod has a `restartPolicy` that can support the `Succeeded` phase.
2. Cause your application to terminate, possibly by sending it `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, or possibly by commanding it via its own API.